# How can I join, aggregate, and pivot data that includes a BLOB column?

Tags: oracle, join, pivot, blob, aggregation

I'm trying to aggregate and pivot data from one table while joining two others. The third table contains a BLOB (which isn't allowed and causes `ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got BLOB`)

What I would like to run (but cannot):

```
SELECT * FROM (
    select p.blah, p.result, p.type, s.blah, b.blob
    from table p
    join table2 s on s.id = p.id
    join tableBlob b on b.id = s.id)
PIVOT  (max(result) FOR (type) IN ('type1' as type1, 'type2' as type2))
where blah = 'value'
ORDER BY blah;
```

How might I achieve the desired results?

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14249/adlob_sql_semantics.htm): _The following categories of functions are not supported for use with LOBs: Aggregate functions..._ And `pivot` is an aggregation.

Comment: Thanks Ponder. Any suggestions on how one can achieve the desired result (or am I supposed to post a new question)?

Comment: I don't know if this suits you, but there are two topics (maybe more) about aggregating and pivoting blobs on asktom site: [1](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=pivot-data-into-named-columns), [2](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:2828105100346499156).

Comment: I think you could pivot data without blob column, but retrieve ID (somehow), and after pivoting join tableBlob. If this is what you want. Sample input data and required output is needed.

Comment: Thanks Ponder. After looking at asktom, I've decided to aggregate in the middle-ware.